# Repetitive Dropdown / Select Menu on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-select

I'm new to Reactjs and using the states.

I checked on some documentations online and saw some examples using

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
```

but what worries me is this form that I'm trying to build.
The form has more than 50 fields that has a dropdown of its own values.

My question is, is it necessary to declare around 50 of these useState const?
Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Necessary, no. A better way, this is subjective. You could declare a single state with the ~50 input keys. Or use something a bit more powerful to handle more complex state, i.e. `useReducer`. Have you tried something already and have an issue or are you just curious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, you can do is to create just one `useState` and create a key, value of its respective fields like

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ field1: "default-value", field2: {}, ... });
```

You can update each field in the state when value update in the form so you can handle it better and easy

Comment: How can we set a value for a specific key like let's say I need to put a value for field1 only without affecting other keys?